# sqlite генерация данных в базу на java

Tags: java, sqlite

дана бд с таблицей

```
create table entry (field Long)
```

после подключения к бд
необходимо сгенерировать данные в базу от 1 до скажем 1000000

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try (PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO entry VALUES (?)")) {
                st.setInt(1, 1 + i);
                st.executeUpdate();
```

и вот такая генерация работает очень медленно
я добавил строчку System.out.println(i);
и долго наблюдаю в консоле 
4103
4104
4105
4106
4107

пока писал вопрос дошло только до сюда можно как-то ускорить процесс?

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько способов решить эту проблему.

1. Начать транзакцию до цикла и зафиксировать после

   ```
   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       ...
   }
   conn.commit();
   ```
2. Использовать пакетные операции

   ```
   try (PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO entry VALUES (?)")) {
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           st.setInt(1, 1 + i);
           st.addBatch();
       }
       st.executeBatch();
   }
   ```
3. Сгенерировать данные не в java-коде, а SQL-запросом

   ```
   insert into entry select * from generate_series(0, 1000000, 1);
   ```